# Why does Stack Exchange ask about cookies on every screen?

Tags: discussion, support, firefox

Every time I open a page on Stack Exchange it wants me to accept all cookies:

> By clicking “Accept all cookies”, you agree Stack Exchange can store cookies on your device and disclose information in accordance with our Cookie Policy.

It doesn't matter whether I click on All Cookies or Necessary Cookies. I always get that prompt. How do I turn it off?

I'm running Firefox 112.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10. NoScript, AdBlock, and Privacy Badger are all okay with the site, not blocking anything.

Solution:
I opened DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials, turned off "Protections for this site", and I don't get the ask to accept cookies (more than once). After reloading the page, I re-enabled the "Protections for this site", and the asks don't come any more. Yay.

Comment: Gently disagree that it's a Meta question. It seems about browser settings or system settings (which are preventing the appropriate cookie from being set). It seems not about AskUbuntu policy, etiquette, and it seems not a site bug. I can reproduce the behavior only by using Privacy Mode on a browser. However, it IS off-topic here because it's a browser-on-Windows support question.

Comment: "I'm running Firefox 112.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10" makes it off topic on AskUbuntu and on Meta. Windows is not for us to answer. and do turn of privacy mode if active ;)

Comment: Just adding a bit from another user using Ubuntu.  I find the same action, sometimes even when I just go to a different question on the same site, it will ask the cookie question again when it just ask on first question.  This seems to have started just in the last week or two.  It does seem to happen mainly when looking at questions on these sites I have not joined yet.  Sites I am a member of do not have the same problem.  It is not just an askubuntu site specific happening.  It might be better on meta stack exchange

Comment: I'll second @Rinzwind. This question should be answered by the company which sold the OS

Comment: This has been happening to me for a very long time as well. And it doesn’t matter what OS or browser I use. I am constantly asked about cookies and repeatedly asked no matter what response I click.

Comment: @Chelmite I'm going to close this here, but you should really post this on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) rather than a site about an Ubuntu Linux distribution's meta.  Since you say this happens on every screen or every site/page/etc you need to talk to Meta.SE really.  Also, if you browse in privacy mode it will never *store* cookies.

Comment: I've observed this recently on both Windows (Firefox 112.0.1) **and** Ubuntu 18.04 (Firefox 112.0.2 Snap). Another symptom is that the "Customize your settings" button doesn't work. In both cases, it appears to be related to the DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials add-on - disabling that (temporarily - it can be re-enabled after making the selection) seems to fix it. I also run UBlock Origin and Privacy Badger but neither of those seems to be involved.